# Why doesn't Rust understand that a reference is no longer borrowed?

Tags: rust, reference, stack, borrow-checker

In Rust when I borrow a value, the compiler takes notice, but when I replace it the compiler does not notice and issues an E0597 error.

Given a mutable variable that contains a reference `x`. When I replace its content, with the reference to a local variable, and before the local goes out of scope I replace it back to the original.

Here is a code that shows this:

```rust
struct X {payload : i32}

fn main() {
    let pl = X{payload : 44};
    {
        let mut x = &pl;
        {
            let inner = X{payload : 30};
            let tmp = std::mem::replace(&mut x, &inner);
            println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
            let _f = std::mem::replace(&mut x, &tmp);
        }
        println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0597]: `inner` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:9:49
   |
9  |             let tmp = std::mem::replace(&mut x, &inner);
   |                                                 ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
12 |         }
   |         - `inner` dropped here while still borrowed
13 |         println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
   |                                 --------- borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

The compiler notices when I assign a reference of `inner` to `x`, but overlooks the fact that while `inner` is still alive I replace this reference with the original one to `pl` again.

The expected output should be:

```
data =30
data =44
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c4df1cad5768f291af91bf487319187b) for a little deeper analysis, couldn't figure it out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing that the lifetimes of references is part of their *type*, and not some dynamically tracked metadata. So in the original code, the lifetime associated with `x` has to stop at the end of the nested block because the lifetime associated with it had to "merge" with the lifetime of `inner`, which ends there. It does not matter that you put it back since that does not change the type.

Now to address the nuances discovered in the [self-answer](/a/74694065/2189130):

> However a small tweak will make it compile without errors or warnings.
>
> ```
> // Compiles without errors/warnings.
> struct X {payload : i32}
>
> fn main() {
>     let pl = X{payload : 44};
>     {
>         let mut x = &pl;
>         println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
>         {
>             let inner = X{payload : 30};
>             x = &inner;
>             println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
>             x = &pl;
>         }
>         println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This makes me believe that there is a compiler bug. Because now the compiler catches that the lifetime of inner decouples from the lifetime of x.
>
> ALAS. When you put the inner block into a separated function the problem comes back. So it was just a case that the Rust compiler has some optimization code-path that was catching the corner case.

The critical knowledge to reason about why some examples work and some don't is largely due to the principle that **the borrow checker does not reason outside the current function body**.

This is seen both ways:

- if you use `std::mem::replace`:

  The borrow checker does not know what `std::mem::replace` does. It only sees that it is a function that takes in a `&mut T`, `T`, and returns `T`. Thus you can see how the it will reject this code because it cannot reason that `x` has its original value. The borrow checker will not look at how `replace` is implemented to reason about the local code.
- if you separate it into a separate function:

  ```
  fn inner_func(x: &mut &X) {
      let inner = X { payload: 30 };
      let tmp: &X = *x;
      *x = &inner;
      println!("data ={:?}", x.payload);
      *x = &tmp;
  }
  ```

  Then the borrow checker sees that it is clearly wrong: `x`'s lifetimes by-construction live outside of the scope of `inner_func` so any local variables will have smaller lifetimes and will be incompatible. In its current form, this is definitely unsound since `println!` could panic and the caller could catch that and end up with a dangling reference. Again, the borrow checker does not look at what `main` is doing to reason about the local code.

  The rest of it fails similarly to the other example using a `tmp` variable. The borrow checker does not reason that this will restore the original lifetime. Call this a missed opportunity if you want, but there's no reason for the compiler to handle this sequence of changes in a special way. You can simple reborrow if you want to shorten the lifetimes to use within a nested scope.

So in summary, it is not a compiler bug, it is simply how the borrow checker is implemented and it works by design. In fact, the *working* example is the ugly duckling and the borrow checker only allows it since it knows the entire lifetime and interactions of `x` and thus can hand-wave away what I wrote at the beginning of my answer.

> What am I doing wrong?

If you have this kind of code in a real use-case, there's no reason to reuse `x`, just make a new reference in the nested scope:

```
struct X { payload: i32 }

fn main() {
    let pl = X { payload: 44 };
    let x = &pl;
    {
        let mut x = x; // reborrow so that the new x can have a smaller scope
        let inner = X { payload: 30 };
        let tmp = std::mem::replace(&mut x, &inner);
        println!("data ={:?}", x.payload);
        let _f = std::mem::replace(&mut x, &tmp);
    }
    println!("data ={:?}", x.payload); // uses original x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. Unfortunately it is a compiler bug or limitation.

The semantically equivalent code, credits for the code goes to someone that has posted part of the answer, but then delete it.

```
// This one will yields error E0597
struct X {payload : i32}

fn main() {
    let pl = X{payload : 44};
    {
        let mut x = &pl;
        println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
        {
            let inner = X{payload : 30};
            let tmp : &X = x;
            x = &inner;
            println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
            x = tmp;
        }
        println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
    }
}
```

This code will yield the same error.

However a small tweak will make it compile without errors or warnings.

```
// Compiles without errors/warnings.
struct X {payload : i32}

fn main() {
    let pl = X{payload : 44};
    {
        let mut x = &pl;
        println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
        {
            let inner = X{payload : 30};
            x = &inner;
            println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
            x = &pl;
        }
        println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
    }
}
```

This makes me believe that there is a compiler bug. Because now the compiler catches that the lifetime of `inner` decouples from the lifetime of `x`.

ALAS. When you put the inner block into a separated function the problem comes back. So it was just a case that the Rust compiler has some optimization code-path that was catching the corner case.

```
// Yields error E0597 again.
struct X {payload : i32}

fn inner_func(x : &mut &X) {
    let inner = X{payload : 30};
    let tmp : &X = *x;
    *x = &inner;
    println! ("data ={:?}", (*x).payload);
    *x = &tmp;
}

fn main() {
    let pl = X{payload : 44};
    {
        let mut x : &X = &pl;
        inner_func(&mut &mut x);
        println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
    }
}
```

Credit goes to [Frederico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491528/federico) for a way to shoehorn the *endless* lifetime to  `inner` 's lifetime to make it bigger, even if this means using unsafe.

```
// This one compiles without errors/warnings.
struct X {payload : i32}

fn inner_func(x : &mut &X) {
    let inner = X{payload : 30};
    let tmp : &X = *x;
    unsafe {
        *x = std::mem::transmute::<_, &'static X>(&inner);
    }
    println! ("data ={:?}", (*x).payload);
    *x = &tmp;
}

fn main() {
    let pl = X{payload : 44};
    {
        let mut x : &X = &pl;
        inner_func(&mut &mut x);
        println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When analysing Rust code, the compiler is conservative and rejects programs for which it cannot determine if there are memory errors or not.

In particular, when the compiler checks `let tmp = ...` in your code it notices that you are storing a reference pointing to a short-lived instance (`inner`) into a reference (`pl`) that is used *after* `inner` goes out of scope. The compiler stops here and reports an error, saying that you *might* have created a dangling reference. It doesn't take into account that immediately after you are restoring the original `pl`. The lifetime abstraction that is currently used for the analysis is not precise enough.

In Rust, you have to structure your code so that the compiler has an easy time checking it. This means, for example, that you have to declare `inner` in the outer scope, or that instead of using references you use types like `Rc`, which replace the compile-time checks with runtime checks performed in the library.

If you *really* want to use unsafe code, you can do as follows, but it is highly discouraged. It is up to you to manually check that the code has no undefined behavior, which is hard to do because there is currently no complete description of what is undefined behavior. From [The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html):

> **Warning:** The following list is not exhaustive. There is no formal model of Rust's semantics for what is and is not allowed in unsafe code, so there may be more behavior considered unsafe. The following list is just what we know for sure is undefined behavior. Please read the [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/index.html) before writing unsafe code.

```rust
struct X {payload : i32}

fn main() {
    let pl = X{payload : 44};
    {
        let mut x = &pl;
        // SAFETY: ...(motivate why the following is ok)
        unsafe {
            let inner = X{payload : 30};
            x = std::mem::transmute::<_, &'static X>(&inner);
            println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
            x = &pl;
        }
        println! ("data ={:?}", x.payload);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rc is using the heap so it is not the same. If the compiler is just too conservative, and unjustifiably so, then can you provide an unsafe way to achieve the same result, using only stack allocation? The lifetime violation should be checked at the closing of the block when "inner" dies, not at the assignment of it.

Comment: Your idea with transmute is very good, but your particular example would have accidentally worked even with out it, look at my complete answer.